# Unable to compare two strings in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi I'm facing a strange issue, i'm unable to compare two strings in a .bat file

```
set mvalue="Yes"
echo %mvalue%

echo %MailAlert%


IF  %MailAlert% == %mvalue% (

    echo "hello world"
}
```

value of `%MailAlert%` is Yes it will be recieved from a java code and i'm printing it by using echo command  and is displaying Yes.

But i dont know why i'm unable to compare those two strings.

Please help me out.

Comment: did you check for invisible characters? new lines? spaces? tabs?  try somethign like `echo foo%MailAlert%bar`. If you have invisible chars, you WON'T see `fooYesbar`

Comment: I just tried what you suggested, echo fooYesbar 
fooYesbar it has no invisible characters

Comment: Get rid of the spaces around the `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the value of `%MailAlert%` just `Yes`? Because the value of `%mvalue%` is `"Yes"`. So, you are comparing `IF Yes == "Yes"` which is false.

Also, your closing `}` should be a `)`.

Comment: "Also, your closing } should be a )".........this is where i done the mistake. It is working now Thank you very much

Comment: And i modified  set mvalue="Yes" to set mvalue=Yes too